# Oracle Java 7 Removing Error!

Tags: 12.04, java, uninstall, oracle

fellow Linuxeers!
So, I've had this problem recently when I tried to remove Oracle's Java 7 after it didn't want to work correctly. So, when I tried to:

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-install
```

I get this error at the end of the code:

```
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were   encountered while processing:
oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

With no other errors in the output.
Now why can't I remove the files? It really is an annoying problem, because every time I install/remove something in the terminal the error shows up.
Help? Thanks on forehand!

Answer (score 3):

First I purge the java installer PPA using following commands:

```
sudo rm oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer
```

Than I signed in to [technet.oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/index.html) using my account ID (registration is free to oracle.com)

I then added the PPA, and this time, it was a success.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I was able to successfully download from oracle.com. I guess sign-in worked.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I tried this, and think it would work but keep running into errors at the very last step. I running debian on a PowerBook G4.By the way I logged in as you suggested. But how does that affect anything?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved that issue by visiting the below link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1977483

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't work, unfortunately 
EDIT: Whoa. the apt-get purge worked! thanks alot man! (girl?)

Comment: NICE - finally someone did well